# Phonegap can't add platform FireFox OS

Tags: firefox, cordova, firefox-os

I have problems adding Firefox OS as a platform to my Cordova project. I tried the simplest way:

installed phonegap globally:

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

created phonegap project:

```
cordova create HelloWorld com.domain.hello HelloWorld
```

CD'd into the new HelloWorld folder, then added iOS as platform:

```
cordova platform add iOS
```

which worked, but when trying to add Firefox OS, I get

***[Error: Platform "firefoxos" not recognized as core cordova platform.]***

I tried updating the platform with:

```
phone gap platform update firefoxos
```

but all I get is

**[phonegap] updating Fire Fox OS platform...**

**[error] Platform "firefoxos" is not installed. See "platform list".**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

You want to use Cordova not PhoneGap (yes, there is a difference).

```
npm install -g cordova
```

then follow along in the link provided.

Additional information related to Cordova and FirefoxOS:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_firefoxos_index.md.html#Firefox%20OS%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: OH. MY. GOD! Such a useless typo! Can I blame on the documentation mixing new and old articles? Thank you!